Virtual device emulator in Andriod Studio doesnt work
I'm trying to work on a project but when I test the device emulator it keeps terminating it. Here is the screenshot of what's happening.
I wanted to try if the emulator works first before I proceed on continuing with the project. I haven't moved anything much. I just added a virtual device from the device manager(downloading SDK component)

I found a solution to my problem. Instead of using an emulator for testing, I just connected my phone as a medium for testing. Works great!
This is how I connected my phone to Android Studios:
Step 1: On the top click the button next to the "app", this is usually where the thing for the emulator is.

Step 2: Select "Pair devices using wifi". A QR Code will pop out.
Step 3: On your phone, enable the developers mode then select the wireless debugging.
Step 4: Select the "pair device over wifi", then scan the QR Code provided by the Android studio.
Then you can just run the project but check first if the selected device for running is your own device and not the Android emulator. Hope this helps future developers.
